# align contents of flex items with other flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a scenario where there is three flex items, showing as boxes, beside eachother which match each others height.

Each contain a title and description
I would like for the top of each title and descriptions within the flex item to align with the other flex items titles and descriptions

The titles and descriptions are from a content system so can take up between 1 and 4 lines, so I can't hardcode the positions without potentially creating unwanted whitespace. The titles do this naturally as they just have a margin separating it from the top of it's container but the descriptions are causimg my difficulty

Note we are using flex box as these items may wrap down to next line depending on user screen
[image: Visual for problem]

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: using a grid in the container, it will work I think because smaller and higher heights will be the same, also width will be the same (between all the card present in the same container) because of the number of cols. and the text that is 1 to 4 make it be always start at the `flex-start` (not centered) so the space will be at the end and not at the start. is this what you need? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zlxn.png if yes i will show you the code

Comment: Edited to include what I am trying to create here